# How can I query an aggregation of values grouped by hour of day from InfluxDB?

Tags: influxdb

## Question

I have an InfluxDB v1.8 running on a Raspberry Pi 2.

I have a measurement "gridElectricityMeter" that has (next to other fields not important here) a field "import" which contains the total reading of the energy meter in Watt-hours. The measurement receives a new value every 10 seconds.

I would like to create a Bar chart that shows the imported amount of energy by hour of day in some time frame to be specified (I am using Grafana to create the chart, so the time frame is set there).

E.g. if the raw data in InfluxDB looks like this:

| time | import |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z | 0 |
| 2021-01-01T01:00:00Z | 2 |
| 2021-01-01T01:20:00Z | 8 |
| 2021-01-01T02:00:00Z | 10 |
| 2021-01-02T00:00:00Z | 10 |
| 2021-01-02T01:00:00Z | 20 |

(In reality there are of course far more values, one value per 10 seconds. A slight lack of precision because the timestamps are likely a few seconds of the full hour may be accepted.)

Then I want the following result:

| hour | sum | explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12 | 2 (first day) + 10 (second day) |
| 1 | 8 | 8 (first day) |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... |  |

Data should be filled with zero if unavailable (e.g. querying "today", of course there is no data for the time after "now").

## What I have tried so far

As far as I understand I won't be able to do this with InfluxQL. So here is what I tried using flux. Also I think I understood that InfluxDB >= 2.0 is 64-bit only and thus won't run on Raspberry Pi 2.

Here is what I came up with:

```
import "date"
import "generate"

// generate a table with 24 entries (hours 0-23) and "sum=0":
initial = generate.from(
  count: 24,
  fn: (n) => n,
  // start and stop are actually irrelevant, but they are required args
  start: 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z,
  stop: 2021-01-02T00:00:00Z,
)
|> map(fn: (r) => ({hour: r._value, sum: 0}))

// First group data by day and hour
data = from(bucket: "myDatabase")
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "gridElectricityMeter" and r._field == "import")
|> map(fn: (r) => ({r with hour: date.hour(t: r._time), group: date.truncate(t: r._time, unit: 1h)}))
|> group(columns: ["group"])

// In each group we get the first&last point so that we get the first and last reading from the energy meter. The difference between those values is the energy imported.
first = data
|> first()

last = data
|> last()

// Calculate energy used in each group and then regroup by hour (and not day):
byhour = join(tables: {first: first, last: last}, on: ["group"])
|> map(fn: (r) => ({r with hour: r.hour_first, _value: r._value_last - r._value_first}))
|> group(columns: ["hour"])
// manual summing because of https://github.com/influxdata/flux/issues/2505
|> reduce(fn: (r, accumulator) => ({sum: accumulator.sum + r._value}), identity: {sum: 0})

// Fill hours we have no data for with zero:
union(tables: [byhour, initial])
|> group(columns: ["hour"])
|> reduce(fn: (r, accumulator) => ({sum: accumulator.sum + r.sum}), identity: {sum: 0})
|> group()
|> sort(columns: ["hour"])
```

It does seem to work and actually do what I want it to do. However it seem ridiculously complicated. And also it is slow. Querying data for a single day takes about 7 seconds. A single day contains 6*60*24=8640 data points in that measurements which really does not sound very much to me and it should not be that slow.

Is there a better way of doing it?